# A question about square roots of quadratic residues.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ ($p$ is a prime) is a cyclic group with generator $g$. We consider a subgroup $\mathbb{G}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ with generator $h$ and order $q$, where $h = g^4~mod~p$ and $q=(p-1)/4$. For an element $y = h^x~mod~p$ in $\mathbb{G}$, we calculate the two square roots of $y$, which are $(g^{2x}~mod~p)$ and $p- (g^{2x}~mod~p)$. I thought one of them should be quadratic residue and the other one is quadratic non-residue. But it seems both of them are quadratic residue (when I power them with $(p-1)/2$, both of them become 1).

Why is this? I thought for any element $a$, $(a^{{(p-1)/2}})^2=1$ always holds, then $a^{{(p-1)/2}}=\pm1$ should always hold.

Comment: In order for your construction to work (i.e. for $q$ to be an integer), you need to assume that $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. In particular, $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Why -1 (which is $4q$) is necessary a quadratic residue mod $p$?

Comment: It's a standard fact that for an odd prime $p$, $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Why $-1$ being quadratic is relevant here? If we calculate the square roots of $h$, we get $g^2$ and $p - g^2$. I think the important thing is why $p-g^2$ is quadratic residue?

Comment: Because $p-g^2\equiv( -1)g^2$ is therefore the product of two quadratic residues.